# Return value for an unset property in php

Tags: php

if I return from a getter and nothing is set for it, what variable type is returned?

like

```
$nb = $prod->getNewDate();
```

assume nothing is set for new date.
what is $nb? null?

Comment: as in getNewDate() doesn't exist, or it's getting a value that doesn't exist in the object?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `var_dump()` on the variable and it will tell you what it is, NULL in this case.

Answer (score 2):

a NULL is then returned, just as a ordinary function.